# The following classes could not be instantiated: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView. Help me?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob

My manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.spdevelopers.work"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/NoTitle" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/sfondo"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.spdevelopers.tensquarefree.MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/titolo" />

[...]

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/AdViewMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
```

ActivityMain.java:

```
package com.spdevelopers.work;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    [...]

    AdView mAdView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.AdViewMain);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Error: The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.

Someone can help me? Thanks

EDIT

Error Log:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.8.0_20
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=it_IT
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

com.android.ide.eclipse.adt
Error
Sat Sep 27 11:35:00 CEST 2014
com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView failed to instantiate.

java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 57
Exception Details:
  Location:
   com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView.onMeasure(II)V @20: ifnull
Reason:
  Expected stackmap frame at this location.
Bytecode:
  0x0000000: 033e 0336 042a 03b6 0015 3a05 2ab6 0014
  0x0000010: 3a06 1905 c600 2519 05b6 000b 1008 9f00
  0x0000020: 1b2a 1905 1b1c b600 1919 05b6 000a 3e19
  0x0000030: 05b6 0009 3604 a700 1f19 06c6 001a 2ab6
  0x0000040: 0016 3a07 1906 1907 b600 133e 1906 1907
  0x0000050: b600 1236 041d 2ab6 0018 b800 2a3e 1504
  0x0000060: 2ab6 0017 b800 2a36 042a 1d1b b800 0d15
  0x0000070: 041c b800 0db6 001a b1                 

at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:367)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:194)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:778)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:500)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:381)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:400)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:329)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:517)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1584)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1309)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.onXmlModelChanged(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1267)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegateXmlModelChanged(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:402)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.xmlModelChanged(CommonXmlEditor.java:329)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor$XmlModelStateListener.modelChanged(AndroidXmlEditor.java:1653)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.wrapEditXmlModel(AndroidXmlEditor.java:1114)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.wrapUndoEditXmlModel(AndroidXmlEditor.java:1190)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.MoveGesture.drop(MoveGesture.java:396)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GestureManager$CanvasDropListener.drop(GestureManager.java:679)
at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DNDListener.handleEvent(DNDListener.java:91)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1085)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1070)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:782)
at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget.Drop(DropTarget.java:456)
at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget.Drop_64(DropTarget.java:392)
at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget$3.method6(DropTarget.java:260)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COMObject.callback6(COMObject.java:119)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COM.DoDragDrop(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DragSource.drag(DragSource.java:363)
at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DragSource.access$0(DragSource.java:289)
at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DragSource$1.handleEvent(DragSource.java:172)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

Comment: Did you try the suggestion in the error message? `See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.`

Answer (score -1):

This is an error from your IDE.

To resolve it don't try and get your IDE to render the AdView. Look at the XML instead (it will give you a better understanding in any case).

The real question is, does it crash at runtime on a device.